# Twig include HTML raw from asset

Tags: twig, symfony

I need to render/show a HTML file, on my page. These HTML file need to be uploaded by someone, and then, render.

Actually, I do it like that. ( `book.htmlsrc` is the name of my file )

```
{{ source('book/html/' ~ book.htmlsrc)}}
```

But I need to store html sources in my app/ressources/view directory.

I tried this, but it isn't working, as it's telling me that the asset is not found. (and in this case, why? asset is here, and render it throught the URL is working)

```
{{ source(asset('assets/book/html/' ~ book.htmlsrc))}}
```

Error is telling this:

```
Unable to find template "/project/web/assets/book/html/abbot_flatland.html"
```

By checking the url `http://127.0.0.1/project/web/assets/book/html/abbot_flatland.html`, I can access it easily.

Here my question.
How can I render a HTML file, located in my assets, on my twig view.

---

**EDIT:** Based on @DarkBee answer, I did the following.

On my config.yml, I added this.

```
twig:
    paths:
        '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/assets/uploads/html': uploads
```

And then, in my twig view, just needed to include the file.

```
{{ include('@uploads/' ~ book.htmlsrc) }}
```

Comment: You could add the additional folder  `assets` as a template folder to twig with `$loader->addPath('/project/web/assets/')`, then you should be able to use `{{ source('book/html/' ~ book.htmlsrc)}}`

Comment: And why not move your file to `app/ressources/view` after uploaded it?

Comment: @DarkBee i'll give a shot with this. ::hokusai Because I "prefer" to let all my asset in my asset directory. Also, already got an upload method, and upload (and scan/process data) on 2 directory instead of one isn't as proper as I want it to be)

Comment: The reason why `{{ source(asset('assets/book/html/' ~ book.htmlsrc))}}` is not working because the `asset` function returns a web relative path while source needs a filesystem path, either absolute or relative to your website root.